# PowerBI: Ranking de canciones en función del número de votos

Tags: powerbi

Tengo una tabla `canciones` con varias columnas, entre ellas `canciones[titulo_cancion])`, con los títulos de las canciones, y `canciones[votos_facebook]`, con el número de votos que ha recibido cada una de ellas.

Querría hacer una medida con la función `RANKX()` para añadirla a una tabla con las dos columnas mencionadas y que me indique el orden de las canciones en función del número de votos.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
clasificacion_canciones = RANKX(ALL(canciones), SUM(canciones[votos_facebook]))
```

Sin embargo, todas las canciones aparecen con el número 1, como si `ALL()` no fuera capaz de eliminar el contexto de fila de cada canción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A qué puede deberse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era envolver la función de agregación en `CALCULATE()`, que por lo visto es mágica. Debería investigarla un poco más porque por lo visto sirve para todo.

```
clasificacion_canciones = RANKX(ALL(canciones), CALCULATE(MAX(canciones[votos_facebook])))
```

Aunque se da un fenómeno peculiar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema viene del segundo argumento que le pasas a la función `RANKX`.
Debería ser:

```
clasificacion_canciones = RANKX(ALL(canciones), canciones[votos_facebook])
```

Es decir, sin el `SUM`, puesto que deseas obtener el ranking de los votos por canción, de otra manera suma los votos totales, y siempre es el mismo valor y por ello todos tienen el mismo ranking. Aunque en tu mente estaba la imagen de suma por canción.

Si la tabla tiene más de una entrada por canción, es decir, tienes que sumar más de una votación por canción, utilza la función SUMX:

```
RANKX(ALL(canciones), SUMX(canciones, canciones[votos_facebook]))
```

Comment: Si no utilizo una función de agregación en `canciones[votos_facebook]`, la fórmula no funciona; y da igual que sea `SUM()` o que sea `MAX()` u otra, siempre salen todas las canciones con valor 1.

Comment: He probado a agrupar los votos por ciudad en vez de por canción, que en ese caso sí tiene sentido usar `SUM()`, pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo; ¿puede tener que ver con mi modelo de datos?